# JAVA GUI - GET and SHOW DATA FROM MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface

I am working on a GUI app with MySQL access. When user enters some data in JTextField 'VendorID', I want it to be searched in the database, find the proper line with information and show all the columns in other JtextFields seperately. Actually I wanted this data to be showed in JLabel but unsuccessful, so trying now with JtextFields. Appreciate any help from you.

```
public void findVendor() {

        String vatEntered = vendorID.getText();


        try
        {
         String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
         String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/masterdata_db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
         Class.forName(myDriver);
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "");

         Statement st = conn.createStatement();


         String check = "SELECT * FROM vendorcreation WHERE VAT = 'vatEntered' ";      
         ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery(check);

         boolean status = true;
         if(resultSet.next()==status){

             nameSelected.setText(resultSet.getString(1));
             adressSelected.setText(resultSet.getString(2));
             countrySelected.setText(resultSet.getString(3));
             vatSelected.setText(resultSet.getString(4));
             ptermsSelected.setText(resultSet.getString(5));

             conn.close();

         }

         else {

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NO DATA FOUND! FIRST YOU MUST CREATE IT", "Inane error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
             dispose();
             new CreateVendor().setVisible(true);        
             }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm understanding, you're having trouble executing the statement?
You need to set up the statement as following:

```
String check = "SELECT * FROM vendorcreation WHERE VAT = " +vatEntered ;
```

But it is better to use a prepared statement instead.

```
String check = "SELECT * FROM vendorcreation WHERE VAT = ?";
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(check);
st.setString(1, vatEntered);
ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery();
```

As for categorizing data, the order seems to depend on the order that the column is in the database. What you can also do is to manually set the result by changing the statement:

```
String check = "SELECT (column1, column2) FROM vendorcreation WHERE VAT = ?"//etc
```

where `resultSet.getString(1);` would be data from column1.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your explanation. I was confused about the statement there and that helped me a lot.